# quantity and ext price being multiplied by three?

Tags: reporting-services

I am building a table in reporting services and am not getting the results I expect.  It appears that my table is taking my data and multiplying  by 3.  In the example below the quantity should be 1 and the ext price should be roughly $322.  I have spot checked a few of these orders in our system and it appears it is doing this across the board. Below is the query I built but I am not sure what is causing the issue.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

```
SELECT
  OrderDetail.Quantity
  ,OrderDetail.PartNo
  ,OrderDetail.UnitPrice
  ,Orders.OrderNumber
  ,Orders.ReqDate
  ,Orders.ShpAddr_City
  ,Orders.ShpAddr_State
  ,act.PartMapping.SalesRevenue
  ,MasterPartList.ProductCategoryID
  ,Categories.Description
  ,OrderDetail.LocationID
  ,Orders.InvAddrCompanyName
  ,Orders.Status
  ,CustomerUserDefValues.UserDefValue
  ,UserDefs.UserDefID
  ,Orders.ClosedDate
FROM
  OrderDetail
  INNER JOIN Orders
    ON OrderDetail.oKey = Orders.oKey
  INNER JOIN act.PartMapping
    ON OrderDetail.PartNo = act.PartMapping.PartNo
  INNER JOIN MasterPartList
    ON OrderDetail.PartNo = MasterPartList.MasterPartNo
  INNER JOIN Categories
    ON MasterPartList.ProductCategoryID = Categories.ID
  INNER JOIN CustomerUserDefValues
    ON Orders.CustomerID = CustomerUserDefValues.CustomerID AND Orders.SiteID = 
    CustomerUserDefValues.SiteID
  INNER JOIN UserDefs
    ON CustomerUserDefValues.UserDefID = UserDefs.UserDefID
 WHERE dbo.UserDefs.[UserDefID] in (@UserDefID) and act.PartMapping.[SalesRevenue] in 
    (@ValueAddAccount)
```

[image]

Comment: This is more of an SQL question than an SSRS one. My guess is one of your tables has multiple records now and may need another JOIN. If it's not obvious by looking at the data you have, my usual modus operandi to identify which table is to add a unique key or identity field from each table to see what records are duplicating.

Comment: I agree with Hannover. Make a copy of your statement, change it to select all columns and add a where clause to filter down to what you think is a single result, then look for instances where you see different values in on of your columns, that will be the table that you either need an additional join, some additional filtering, or aggregating.